# Could not install blackberry application

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-jde

I developed an application using the JRE 7.0.0. In the simulator the app works fine, but when I tried to install this application in the 9300 with OS 6.0.0 it doesn't work. Do I need to recompile the application with JRE 6.0.0 or can I change something in the .alx file???

Here's my .alx

```
<loader version="1.0">
<application id="Sistema">
    <name >

    </name>
    <description >

    </description>
    <version >
        1.0.0
    </version>
    <vendor >
        BlackBerry Developer
    </vendor>
    <copyright >
        Copyright (c) 2011 BlackBerry Developer
    </copyright>
    <fileset Java="1.54" _blackberryVersion="[7.0.0)">
        <directory >
            7.0.0
        </directory>
        <files >
            Sistema.cod

        </files>

    </fileset>

</application>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compile your file with blackberry jde version 6, then it will run. There is no **backward compatibility.** If you compile the file with jde version 7 it will run on blackberry version 7 or greater and will not run on blackberry 6 and if you compile it with version 6 it will run on version 6 and greater than version 6.